# Docker container only on network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I use Docker and I have multiple webapps each need a MySQL server. Actually each webapp use his own bridge network to communicate with his MySQL server but each MySQL server use a different port (3306, 3307, 3308 ...).

I can't run them all on the port 3306 because this one is already used by the first MySQL webapp's.

Is it possible to do something to run all on MySQL servers on the 3306 ?

What I have :

| ***Net1 (bridge)*** |    ***Net2(bridge)***  | ***Net3(bridge)*** | ***....*** |
|--------------------|----------------------|--------------------|-----|
| Webapp1:80   | Webapp2:8080 | Webapp3:8081  |  ... |
| Mysql:3306     | Mysql:3307      | Mysql:3308     | ... |

What I would like:

| ***Net1 (bridge)*** |    ***Net2(bridge)***  | ***Net3(bridge)*** | ***....*** |
|--------------------|----------------------|--------------------|-----|
| Webapp1:80   | Webapp2:8080 | Webapp3:8081  |  ... |
| Mysql:3306     | Mysql:3306      | Mysql:3306     | ... |

How I run my containers:

```
docker network create --driver bridge webapp1net
docker run -d -p 3306:3306\
  --net=webapp1net \
  --net-alias=[webapp1net] \
  -h webapp1-mysql \
  --name webapp1-mysql mysql 

docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:80\
  --net=webapp1net \
  --net-alias=[webapp1net] \
  -h webapp1 \
  --name webapp1 webapp1
```

Thanks

Old post:

> With ***Docker***, I would like to know if it's possible to ***expose*** a container only ***on the network and not on the host***.
>
> Example:
>   I have 3 services each on a network and use MySQL but I don't want to change the MySQL's port.
>
> Net 1 : myapp:80 (accessible by the localhost) & MySQL:3306 (only on the network)
>
> Net 2 : myapp:8080 (accessible by the localhost) & MySQL:3306 (only on the network)
>
> etc.
>
> Is it possible to do something by running MySQL on `0.0.0.0` ?
>
> Thanks

Comment: By "network" do you mean a docker bridge network? Anything inside a container has it's own network stack so you can have something listening on the docker host on 3306, and in each container on 3306. There won't be clashes

Comment: question is not clear; Can you please provide more information. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answers I update my post, I hope to be more clearly